# styled-components with custom React components: passing props

Tags: reactjs, button, components, styled-components

I have a custom component that takes in a property icon and sets the button's inner image to the corresponding icon as follows:

```
<custom-button-icon ref={showIcon} slot="right" icon="tier1:visibility-show" onClick={() => isPasswordVisible(false)} />
```

I would like to apply custom styling to a couple of instances of this component using styled-components. How can I pass the icon prop in so that it still functions (gets passed in as a pop of `custom-button-icon`)? This is what I have so far but it returns an empty button (with no icon):

```
export const d2lButtonIcon = ({ icon }) => {
  const buttonIcon = styled(`d2l-button-icon`)`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 100px;
    margin: 1px;
`
  return <buttonIcon icon={icon} />
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a really unusually case because this [`d2l-button-icon`](https://github.com/BrightspaceUI/core/tree/master/components/button) that you are dealing with a custom HTML element rather than a React component.

`styled-components` can style any React component and any built-in DOM element (`a`, `div`, etc.), but I don't think it knows how to deal with a custom DOM element because that's just not the way that we build things in React.

At first I tried passing the style to the `d2l-button-icon` element, and I got the `icon` prop to pass through but the style was ignored.

The way that I got this to work is to apply the styles to a `div` around the element and pass the other props to the `d2l-button-icon` element itself.

```
// function component adds styles around the icon button
const UnstyledD2L = ({ className, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <d2l-button-icon {...props} />
    </div>
  );
};

// can use styled-component to style this wrapper component
const StyledButtonIcon = styled(UnstyledD2L)`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 100px;
  margin: 1px;
`;

// example usage with props
export default () => <StyledButtonIcon text="My Button" icon="tier1:gear" />;
```

However if you aren't super attached to this Brightspace package, I would recommend switching to a UI library that is designed for React.